# Recommendations for SharePoint 2010 training?

Tags: development, learning, training

I have a $2,000 training budget this year, so I'm looking for the best bang for the buck.  The $2k would have to include travel, if any is required, and I'm based in Raleigh, NC.  I would like to focus on SharePoint 2010 (we'll be migrating from 2007 to 2010 by the end of the year).  My role is a project manager with a development background, but my duties include some light farm administration, some custom code development, some governance, and mostly design/development guidance.  However, I would like to focus on the area that would be best for my career in the future, leaning more toward development than administration, yet still fall within my current role well enough that I could justify the training need.

Can anyone recommend some good options?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of excellent training resources at the moment from Microsoft available. For only 2k in budget my suggestion would be to maybe invest in the free training and then purchase the vast array of SharePoint 2010 books that will be available in the near future.

Some of training that I have done and recommend:

- [Channel 9 SharePoint Developer Videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SharePoint2010Developer/): Great overview by Andrew OConnell and Ted Pattison on some of the new features of 2010
- [SharePoint Ignite Training from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2009/08/27/sharepoint-2010-partner-training-for-sharepoint-2007-partners.aspx): Both the IT Professional and Development Courses were excellent and can be done in their own time. Currently I think that this is available to partners only but it looks like some organisations are offering out as well.
- [SharePoint 2010 Beta Developer Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bfd1603b-7550-4b8e-be85-4215a5069b90&displaylang=en): Basic training from Microsoft again

There is also a whole bunch of oranisations offering training. Personally I only get real value out of courses if its held by someone who actually knows what they are talking about. I know that some of the MVP's frequently do these so they may be worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

Two of the best training options are Mindspring and CriticalPath.  There may be options to take the training online which can save you a few dollars plus travel expenses.

I would also like to plug the local user group at http://www.trispug.com which can provide some local contacts and networking opportunities.